# Efficiently managing CD importing of med images, PDFs, audios, etc

Tags: windows, automation, document-management, document-converter, optical-media

I work for a law firm supporting almost 100 users in their day to day operations. In addition to my IT tasks I handle all incoming CDs and flash drives that need to be manipulated and then uploaded to Imanage Filesite 9 (our document management system) using the Outlook add-in where it is profiled and added to the proper matter.

I am on a search to find a script / program / resource to automate or simplify what I need to do. Below is a list of the processes I need to handle.

1. Determine CD contents.
2. PDFs are combined into as few 150MB or smaller files as possible and uploaded.
3. Medical image viewers are zipped and uploaded as is.
4. Audios are converted to MP3 and then uploaded.
5. Videos are converted to ASF and then uploaded.

Is there anything that can monitor the CD drive, determine what file types are on the disc, and then activate an action accordingly? Is there a better way that I can do this? Far too much of my time is spent on handling incoming media than I would like (or my superiors would like for that matter).

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. I don't have a hard limit for budget. I don't think my superiors would go for anything over a few thousand as a one time expense. Freeing up the massive amount of time wasted from manually importing all of these CDs would add up to a huge boost in productivity.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a difficult program to write. If you don't have a programmer on staff, you could hire a consultant to write it.